# ChromeOS app EditText shows an user suggestion when I try to write an account. And blocks keyboard

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, chromebook, search-suggestion

This is my EditText

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/credentials_user_name"
                style="@style/editTextCredentialsText"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_login_input_fields"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_login_input_fields"
                android:hint="@string/user_name" />
```

I also tried inputType = textNoSuggestions but no luck.
This is what happens:
[image]

From that point on I can press on TAB or UP/DOWN keys to navigate through list. But I cannot write anything else in the EditText. Any other key including ESC does nothing

Answer (score 0):

It's embarrassing that such a blatant bug is still present in ChromeOS. The only way I've found to avoid it is to use `android:importantForAutofill="no"` to disable autofill on the affected EditTexts. Or, if you want to disable it only for ChromeOS, do something like this:

```
if (isChromeOS() && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    editTextName.importantForAutofill = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO
}
```